# With MSBuild (VS2012), how do I intercept the path of an assembly file before it's generated?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I want to inject into all my .vcxproj (Visual C++ 2012) projects a custom MSBuild task that gets as input the file path of:

- the assembly (.exe or .dll) and .pdb that are about to be generated
- any other file that gets copied to the output folder along with the binaries

The task then does some operations using those paths before letting the build proceed to the actual generation of the assemblies and the copy to the output folder. How would I go about this?

I've done a lot of research before asking this, but MSBuild examples are pretty scarce and usually involve one or two semi-hardcoded paths, not piping the name of all files about to be created/copied through a custom task.

(If you're curious, the operations could involve checking whether the file already exists and is read-only, is locked by a program, is not checked out in Perforce, and then taking appropriate action.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single item which contains *all* files which eventually make it to the output directory. That is basically an impossible task to achieve since any custom target added can copy files to the output directory. If you want all of them you'll have to manually figure it out. To do this you run the build with verbosity set to `Detailed` (Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run in VS, or pass /v:d on the commandline) and look for lines containing the output files you're after. For example at some point you'd see

```
Target "Link" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets"
...
Outputs for ....
  my.EXE
  my.PDB
```

Then you know the target named Link eventually outputs the exe and the pdb, and you can figure out which properties contain those paths by opening that .targets file in a text editor. You'll see the Link target calls the Link task, which has the aptly named OutputFile and ProgramDatabaseFile inputs. That's the ones you're after and they are set to %(Link.OutputFile) and %(Link.ProgramDatabaseFile). The `%` notation meaning metadata being referenced so Link is in fact not a property an [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items) which is the MSBuild equivalent of an array so in theory it's possible there are e.g. multiple .pdb files. Then write a target to gather all those files in an Item and pass them to a custom task like this:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll" >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <AllOutputFiles ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Output="True"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
    //code here
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="Link">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AllOutputFiles Include="@(Link->MetaData('ProgramDatabaseFile')->FullPath()->Distinct());@(Link->MetaData('OutputFile')->FullPath()->Distinct())"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="AllOutputFiles = @(AllOutputFiles)" />
  <MyCustomTask AllOutputFiles="@(AllOutputFiles)" />
</Target>
```

The `BeforeTargets="Link"` parts makes sure this runs before the linker. If that is too late for some reason, there are many other targets you can use: again look in the detailed output and pick one.

Comment: Thank you, great "teach a man to fish" answer. The verbosity setting combined with the custom task to gather the file paths from the Link (or any other) task's Items were all I needed.